# Angular2 Two Way Binding variable after connected with BLE

Tags: angular

i need a quick look over a code

```
export class DevicePage {

  private device: any;
  public disconnected: any;
  public  connected: any;
  private characteristics: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public ble: BLE) {
   console.log('Device loaded');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.device = this.navParams.get("device");
    this.disconnected = true;
    this.connected = false;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.connect(this.device.id);

    }, 5000);

  }

  connect(deviceID) {
    //console.log('Device loaded ' + deviceID);
    this.characteristics = [];

    var that = this;
    this.ble.connect(deviceID).subscribe(peripheralData => {
      console.log("**** connected ****");
      console.log(peripheralData);
      that.disconnected = false;
      that.connected = true;
      that.characteristics = peripheralData.characteristics;
    },
    peripheralData => {
      console.log("**** disconnected ****");
      console.log(peripheralData);
      that.disconnected = true;
      that.connected = false;
    });


  }

}
```

The problem is when connected it doesn't reflect  connected variable on the html template.

If `replace that.connected = true;` and put it above, just after `this.caracteristics = [];` I can see it right away on my html template

Anyone has any idea why I cant see the change on my template?

Answer (score 0):

So just for other poor guys that will get to the same frustration I got the solution for this. Actually is a problem of rendering the new values over the template. The solution :

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, pu blic ble: BLE, private zone:NgZone) {}

   and

ble.connect(this.device.id).subscribe(peripheralData => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
      console.log("**** connected ****");
      console.log(this);

      this.deviceDisconnected = false;
      this.deviceConnected = true;
      this.characteristics = peripheralData.characteristics
  });

  },
  peripheralData => {
    console.log("**** disconnected ****");
    console.log(peripheralData);

    this.deviceDisconnected = true;
    this.deviceConnected = false;
  });
}
```

So this.zone.run(()=>{}) will do the trick. Hope it helps someone

Cheers

Comment: The reason of this problem is that you are trying to update your property from an asynchrone method.

Comment: ok... but it did the same thing when I called from async an function isConnected()